# How to create a PDF and add the contents usnig iText library in android...?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am using iText library to create PDF documents.
I am able to create and add contents to the document programmetically like "new Paragraph("This is new pdf")".
My question are

1. Can I add the
   contents by typing something in the
   document and save it as PDF using
   iText library? As like we are
   creating word documents...?
2. Suppose if I want to insert an image in my
   document, it will be done by picking
   an image from my External storage
   using a dialog box...?
3. Is it possible using iText library in
   andriod...?

Answer (score 0):

These are multiple questions. I'll try answering them all. However it seems one answer to all your questions is, *first try, study, learn what iText is about, then ask questions*

> but my question is can i able to add
>   the contents by typing something in
>   the document and save it as PDF using
>   iText library? like we are creating
>   word documents...?

No, you have to do it programmatic. iText is not a WYSIWYG tool like Adobe Acrobat or other GUI-PDF Editors.

> suppose if i want to insert a image in my document, it will be done by picking an image from my External storage using a dialog box...

If you create the dialog box and the code logic to add it to a PDF in the iText way it is possible.

> is it possible using iText library in
>   android...?

The general available iText is not fit for Android. You can contact iText Sales department to know more about iText Android.